# How to avoid generating duplicate data with seed method using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a seed method which fills up my database with some seed data. It works for the most part but my directors are being duplicated. Of course this is not what I want. Here's the code:

```
protected override void Seed(MovieModel.MovieContext context)
    {
        var genres = new List<Genre>
        {
            new Genre{Description = "Action", Movies = new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Title = "The Expandables", Duration = 120, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Silvester", LastName = "Stallone"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "The Expandables II", Duration = 96, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Silvester", LastName = "Stallone"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "The Expandables III", Duration = 86, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Silvester", LastName = "Stallone"
                }}
            }},
            new Genre{Description = "Thriller", Movies = new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Title = "Pulp Fiction", Duration = 110, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Quentin", LastName = "Tarrantino"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "Inglorious Bastards", Duration = 142, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Quentin", LastName = "Tarrantino"
                }}
            }},
            new Genre{Description = "Fantasy", Movies = new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Title = "The Fellowship of the Ring", Duration = 220, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Jackson"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "The Two Towers", Duration = 210, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Jackson"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "The Return of the King", Duration = 230, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Jackson"
                }}
            }},
            new Genre{Description = "Horror", Movies = new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Title = "Texas Chainsaw Massacre", Duration = 86, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Wayne", LastName = "Rooney"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "Annabelle", Duration = 90, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Cristiano", LastName = "Ronaldo"
                }}
            }},
            new Genre{Description = "Science Fiction", Movies = new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Title = "Interstellar", Duration = 245, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "Gareth", LastName = "Bale"
                }},
                new Movie{Title = "Pandorum", Duration = 90, Director = new Director
                {
                    FirstName = "David", LastName = "Beckham"
                }}
            }}
        };

        genres.ForEach(g => context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Description, g));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The Director, Movie and Genre class have simple get and set properties and navigation properties. As it currently is the genres and movies are inserted without duplicate data. However Silvester Stallone is inserted 3 times as a director. How do I solve this?

Comment: Quentin Tarrantino will also be inserted twice, right?

Comment: Yes, all directors which have multiple movies will be inserted multiple times.

Comment: Plz show how you are inserting it into database because as UI can see you have 3 movies with same director and what you want? expected result?

Comment: I don't have a UI yet. I'm using Packet Manager Console running the update-database command to run the seed method. When it works without duplicate data I'll create a UI using windows forms to provide CRUD functionality. Right now I just want Silvester Stallone to be added as one record, but he can direct mutiple movies.

Comment: what abt adding them seperately. i mean adding directors and then movies and then genres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating multiple instances `Director` - EF has no way to know that if it sees two instances of `Director` with the same first & last name it should only create a single row, so it creates two rows.

At a guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
protected override void Seed(MovieModel.MovieContext context)
{
    var stallone = new Director { FirstName = "Silvester", LastName = "Stallone" };
    var tarrantino = new Director { FirstName = "Quentin", LastName = "Tarrantino" };
    var jackson = new Director { FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Jackson" };
    var rooney = new Director { FirstName = "Wayne", LastName = "Rooney" };
    var ronaldo = new Director { FirstName = "Cristiano", LastName = "Ronaldo" };
    var bale = new Director { FirstName = "Gareth", LastName = "Bale" };
    var beckham = new Director { FirstName = "David", LastName = "Beckham" };

    var genres = new List<Genre>
    {
        new Genre{Description = "Action", Movies = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie{Title = "The Expandables", Duration = 120, Director = },
            new Movie{Title = "The Expandables II", Duration = 96, Director = stallone},
            new Movie{Title = "The Expandables III", Duration = 86, Director = stallone}
        }},
        new Genre{Description = "Thriller", Movies = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie{Title = "Pulp Fiction", Duration = 110, Director = tarrantino},
            new Movie{Title = "Inglorious Bastards", Duration = 142, Director = tarrantino}
        }},
        new Genre{Description = "Fantasy", Movies = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie{Title = "The Fellowship of the Ring", Duration = 220, Director = jackson},
            new Movie{Title = "The Two Towers", Duration = 210, Director = jackson},
            new Movie{Title = "The Return of the King", Duration = 230, Director = jackson}
        }},
        new Genre{Description = "Horror", Movies = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie{Title = "Texas Chainsaw Massacre", Duration = 86, Director = rooney},
            new Movie{Title = "Annabelle", Duration = 90, Director = ronaldo}
        }},
        new Genre{Description = "Science Fiction", Movies = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie{Title = "Interstellar", Duration = 245, Director = bale},
            new Movie{Title = "Pandorum", Duration = 90, Director = beckham}
        }}
    };

    genres.ForEach(g => context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Description, g));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I.e. only create a single instance of `Director` for each row you want in your database.

(You would end up having the same problem if you had the same film in multiple Genres)

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I solved it using a similar approach, but instead I created a list of directors and I used context.Directors.Find(1) and so on to assign a director to a movie